# What is a good utility to monitor for intrustion attempts while on public WiFi?

Tags: security, wireless-networking

A friend of mine posed a question about how he could secure his laptop when connecting to public WiFi hotspots.  He considers encryption of sensitive files a good idea and he has already downloaded a good encryption package.

Are there any good utilities which can monitor his WiFi adapter and let him know when intrusion attempts take place as well as block them?

Comment: Intrusion via public wifi is probably a considerably lesser concern than sending data unencrypted.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is called a Firewall.  There are basic firewalls built into current operating systems.  I see a few superuser questions that talk about the ones in [Windows XP](https://superuser.com/questions/17504/is-the-windows-xp-firewall-good-enough) and [Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/11426/do-i-need-a-third-party-firewall-for-windows-7) if you're on either of those OSes.

Comment: I think he wants something a bit more functional than just a firewall.  If you remember the program Black Ice, that was a firewall which also had some nice intrusion attempt detection capabilities.  I know the windows firewall logs all of this information, but I do not see it notifying you in cases where intrusion attempts are happening.  I consider this a useful feature. If I thought someone was trying to hack my system the first thing I would do is turn the WiFi off and go somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

I second the VPN answer.  You can use a ssh tunnel to your own home network and browse the net from there.  It's much easier than a full VPN.  Google "tomato ssh tunnel" and you'll see some variations.  Once you setup putty,  there is only one change to set in fire fox or Ie.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably to VPN to a remote/secure network.

Answer (score 0):

It feels like overkill for a single system but [Snort](http://www.snort.org/) sounds like what you want, from what you're saying

Answer (score 0):

[Best free security suites](http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-firewall.htm):

[Comodo Internet Security](http://personalfirewall.comodo.com/)

> Its Defense+ HIPS performance exceeds
> commercial products and leads the
> class, it includes an excellent
> "memory firewall" feature, and it
> allows you to quickly switch between
> Defense+ security modes and
> configurations. Includes automatic
> updates. Installation can
> automatically configure your PC to use
> the Comodo SecureDNS (but you can do
> this without installing CIS).
>
> It was the heaviest on memory
> resources of all top picks. The
> automatic installation mode popups are
> very annoying and much better handled
> in Online Armor. It also comes with an
> optional antivirus that bloats its
> download size to 3 times the other
> products. You get 3 pre-checked
> nags/options during installation. I
> didn't find Threatcast very active or
> helpful at all as of yet.

[Online Armor Free](http://www.tallemu.com/products.php) (the commercial version is my favorite)

> Excellent proactive security performance. Includes a "run safer" feature to reduce
> rights for specific risky applications, a helpful security wizard to minimize popup
> alerts, and the ability to monitor key logger activity and host files. It handles the
> installation of new programs better than any other tested product. You can also close
> its tray icons to save memory and it still functions fully.
>
> It doesn't have automatic updates or a built-in help. It's mandatory to enter an email
> during installation, and it has a pre-checked option to send it anonymous information. I
> also noticed an advertisement popup for its commercial product (but I could check to
> disable them). Windows Vista gave me two security warnings during installation: "Windows
> can't verify the publisher of this driver software" (details: some OA drivers don't have
> a valid digital signature it seems, but OA is a safe application to install obviously).

[PC Tools Firewall Plus](http://www.pctools.com/firewall/)

> Provides excellent proactive security performance comparable to Comodo. The installation
> and initial setup is amazingly easy, the popup alert format is fairly simplistic, and
> the full screen or "game mode" works nicely to prevent popup alerts. Includes default
> profiles to quickly personalize network rules. Automatically updates.
>
> Doesn't have an installation/training mode, so installing new programs can be
> frustrating. Some network profiles may not get perfect GRC stealth results, such as
> "home" for me (but it passed all my other inbound tests). It fails the Zemana key logger
> test in its default settings (but it passes the test when I disable "automatically allow
> applications with valid signatures"). Minimal built-in help, and doesn't break active
> connections. You also get a pre-checked option to install a Spyware Doctor evaluation
> during installation.